# Convert PostGIS polygon as GeoJSON in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I have some polygons saved in postgres using postgis and now I need some way to convert this data to a GeoJSON file so I can display it over google maps.

Here is an example of a polygon in postgis

```
"POLYGON ((-40 145, -40 145, -40 145, -40 145, -40 145, -40 145))"
```

How could I convert this to the equivalent polygon in GeoJSON?

Comment: PostGIS provides the [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) function.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring Could you give an example how this is used in rails?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a Rails person but this [package](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) might get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just creating some JSON with `.exterior_ring.points.map{|point|{lng:point.x, lat:point.y}}` and displaying that on google maps in the same way that flightPlanCoordenants are used in the example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo-geojson is a specific gem for the purpose.

Your code should look like follow:

```
RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(<your_spatial_variable>, json_parser: :json)
```